# How to generate OAuth token using certificate in azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, botframework, bot-framework-composer

Have to generate Oauth2 token using certificate in azure. I have uploaded the certificate in App registration in certificate and secret. In azure bot, under settings-> configurations-> Add Oauth connection Settings; in service provider select Azure active directory V2, there I'm able to see client secret only how to do it in certificate[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbIQ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it appears that Azure Bot resources do not support the usage of certificates for AADv2 auth. While the App Registration may support certificates, they are used across various different types of apps. Thus, not every app type will necessarily support every feature that the App Registration does.

For further reference, here is the Bot Framework documentation on [user authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).